# Plot a hierarchy tabs in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have been trying to plot a hierarchy tabs in R markdown but somehow when I knit the document it does not show the tabs. I was expecting: Score should have Plots and Plots123 as sub tab and Score1 should be aligned with Score tab. But my output does not show any tabs.
PS: (I have purposely written `` while defining a chunk because Stack overflow interprets '```' as code)

```
## Score {.tabset}

### Plots
``
{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
``
### Plots123
``{r pressure_1, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
``
## Scores1 {.tabset}
``{r pressure_2, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
``
```

Comment: I believe that `Plots` and `Plots123` should be `sub-headers` of `Score`. In that case, make sure these tabs are lower header levels. Try using higher header level `##` for `Score` and `Scores1` and lower level `###` for `Plots` and `Plots123`

Comment: I am really sorry actually I had done the same way which you had mentioned still no results

Comment: Maybe it is the spacing. Try my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version - this seems to work. Try this out exactly and let me know.

For [rmarkdown](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/rmarkdown.pdf), all *sub-headers* of the header with the `.tabset` attribute appear within tabs rather than as standalone sections. Also, trying additional spacing between headers.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
date: "2/29/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Score {.tabset}

### Plots
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

### Plots123
```{r pressure_1, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

## Scores1 {.tabset}
```{r pressure_2, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````